# How to find html-table ID

Tags: java, html

I'd like to parse over a table and download it via Jsoup-Java. I know that I can use the function `getElementById` for that purpose. My problem is now: How can I find that id in the html-code of a website?
As an example, I will give the first table in [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19-Pandemie_in_Deutschland) wikipedia-article.

Comment: try inspecting the source code of the html page and look for the element that you are searching for. The id property is not mandatory, so, no guarantee that it'll be there

Comment: Can I post an answer in python or ruby or something?

Comment: @ppablo I think he wants to get the table contents and download them automatically to use them on a website.

Comment: do try to find id, use selector:

select("table").first();

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW his question is about hot to find the id in the html code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this python script will help you to download the source code of a website:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("https://support.image-line.com/member/profile.php?module=Unlock").read()

f = open("source.html", 'wb')
f.write(html)
f.close()
```

Then you trim the file contents using also python, so you delete contents before the `<tbody>` tag and after closing it.

Example:

```
with open("source.html", "r") as f:
   content = f.read()
   position = content.find("<tbody>")
   content = content[position:]
   split_string = content.split("</tbody>", 1)

   substring = split_string[0]
   with open("table.html", "w") as out:
      out.write(substring)
      out.close()
   f.close()
```

Now you will get a file named "table.html", that contains the table.